# Excel VBA: Copy data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

So I am creating a macro, following is part of my code :

```
 Windows("Copy.xlsb").Activate
 Range("AB66").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("Paste.xlsx").Activate
```

I am just creating a macro for copying and pasting information from different workbooks.I would like this to continuous run, changing the Range by one cell i.e for the next iterations the ranges to be copied from will be Range("AC66"),("AD66"),("AE66") and so on. The columns are only changes. How can I put that into the code above.

Comment: Is this code in the copy-workbook or in a 3rd workbook? What is the copy-worksheet's name? What is the last cell that needs to be copied? What is the paste-worksheet's name? Which are the paste-cells i.e. To which cells do the copy-cells get copied? Will the files always be open? If not, where are they located? Please share more of your code. Share any additional information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74139189/edit) at any time.

Comment: Google 'VBA loops' - you'll want a loop, iterating by one column each time. Per the above comment I can't add a fuller answer without more details of your code/scenario to go off.